# Weird placement of EditText's error?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I use [EditText.setError(CharSequence)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setError(java.lang.CharSequence)) to validate my dialog. It shows appropiately, but when calling setError the first time, it does not perform properly. But please, see for yourself:

**Wrong Error**
[image: Wrong Error]

**Correct Error**
[image]

The only thing I did inbetween was pressing the button in my dialog a second time, which causes to setError again.

I use HoloEverywhere in Combination with ActionBarSherlock, but it happens with 'normal' Android widgets too.

I got no clue about this *weird* behaviour, please tell me if you got one.

Thanks in advance, Till

Comment: Testing on emulator or device?

Comment: I'm testing it on the Emulator(Android 4.2 with Intel HAXM image)

Comment: Have you tried it on a real device?